# I can't import class that generated using annotation via databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, android-databinding, annotation-processing

I generated a class with below annotation generator.

```
@AutoService(Processor::class)
class GenerateSealedGettersProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {
    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): MutableSet<String> {

        return mutableSetOf(GenerateSealedGetters::class.java.name)
    }

    override fun getSupportedSourceVersion(): SourceVersion {
        return SourceVersion.latest()
    }

    override fun init(processingEnv: ProcessingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnv)
    }

    override fun process(
        annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>?,
        roundEnv: RoundEnvironment
    ): Boolean {
        val elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(GenerateSealedGetters::class.java)
        for (element in elements) {
            val interfaceElement = element as TypeElement
            generateFunctionsForInterface(interfaceElement)
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun generateFunctionsForInterface(interfaceElement: TypeElement) {
        val packageName = processingEnv.elementUtils.getPackageOf(interfaceElement).toString()
        val className = interfaceElement.simpleName.toString()
        var classNameElements = emptyMap<String, List<Element>>()
        var varTypes: List<String> = emptyList()


        interfaceElement.enclosedElements
            .map {
                if (it.simpleName.toString() != "DefaultImpls") {
                    var enclosedElements = emptyList<Element>()
                    for (enclosedElement in it.enclosedElements) {
                        if (enclosedElement.kind == ElementKind.FIELD && enclosedElement.simpleName.toString() != "INSTANCE") {
                            varTypes = varTypes.plus(enclosedElement.asType().toString())
                            enclosedElements = enclosedElements.plus(enclosedElement)
                        }
                    }
                    classNameElements =
                        classNameElements.plus(it.simpleName.toString() to enclosedElements)
                }
            }


        val builderFile = processingEnv.filer.createSourceFile("$packageName.${className}Functions")
        val writer = PrintWriter(builderFile.openWriter())

        writer.println("package $packageName;")
        writer.println("import ${packageName}.${className};")
        varTypes.iterator().forEach {
            writer.println("import ${it};")
        }

        writer.println("class ${className}Functions {")


        for (element in classNameElements) {
            writer.println("        public static boolean is${element.key}(${className} obj) {")
            writer.println("            return obj instanceof ${className}.${element.key};")
            writer.println("        }")

            for (enclosedElement in element.value) {
                val firstLetter = enclosedElement.simpleName.toString().first().uppercaseChar()
                val simpleName =
                    enclosedElement.simpleName.toString().replaceFirstChar { firstLetter }
                writer.println(
                    "        public static ${
                        enclosedElement.asType().toString()
                    } get${element.key}$simpleName(${className} obj) {"
                )
                writer.println("            if (obj instanceof ${className}.${element.key}) {")
                writer.println("                return ((${className}.${element.key}) obj).get${simpleName}();")
                writer.println("            } else {")
                writer.println("                return null;")
                writer.println("            }")
                writer.println("        }")
            }
        }
        writer.println("}")
        writer.close()

    }
}
```

Generated class is like below and at correct path.

```
package com.app.dnotes.features.select_category.ui;
import com.app.dnotes.features.select_category.ui.SelectCategoryUIState;
import com.app.dnotes.features.base.domain.CustomException;
import com.app.dnotes.features.select_category.ui.SuccessStateData;
class SelectCategoryUIStateFunctions {
        public static boolean isError(SelectCategoryUIState obj) {
            return obj instanceof SelectCategoryUIState.Error;
        }
        public static com.app.dnotes.features.base.domain.CustomException getErrorErrorStateData(SelectCategoryUIState obj) {
            if (obj instanceof SelectCategoryUIState.Error) {
                return ((SelectCategoryUIState.Error) obj).getErrorStateData();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public static boolean isLoading(SelectCategoryUIState obj) {
            return obj instanceof SelectCategoryUIState.Loading;
        }
        public static boolean isSuccess(SelectCategoryUIState obj) {
            return obj instanceof SelectCategoryUIState.Success;
        }
        public static com.app.dnotes.features.select_category.ui.SuccessStateData getSuccessStateData(SelectCategoryUIState obj) {
            if (obj instanceof SelectCategoryUIState.Success) {
                return ((SelectCategoryUIState.Success) obj).getStateData();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

When I tried to import from my UI file via databinding, It can't find my class.

```
<layout
   ...>

<data>
        <import type="com.app.dnotes.features.note.ui.NoteUIStateFunctions" />
</data>
...
</layout>
```

With below error:
Cannot resolve type 'NoteUIStateFunctions'

```
2023-10-14T17:48:21.272+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-14T17:48:21.274+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2023-10-14T17:48:21.276+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-14T17:48:21.276+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2023-10-14T17:48:21.276+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
2023-10-14T17:48:21.276+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2023-10-14T17:48:21.277+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2023-10-14T17:48:21.278+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2023-10-14T17:48:21.285+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 15s
```

My stacktrace logs are below;

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
error: Cannot resolve type 'NoteUIStateFunctions'
error: cannot generate view binders android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: failure, see logs for details.
  Cannot resolve type 'NoteUIStateFunctions'
        at android.databinding.tool.util.L.printMessage(L.java:134)
        at android.databinding.tool.util.L.e(L.java:107)
        at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.getResolvedType(Expr.java:391)
        at android.databinding.tool.expr.ExprModel.lambda$resolveTypes$1(ExprModel.java:626)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at android.databinding.tool.expr.ExprModel.resolveTypes(ExprModel.java:626)
        at android.databinding.tool.expr.ExprModel.seal(ExprModel.java:418)
        at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.sealModel(LayoutBinder.java:245)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.sealModels(DataBinder.java:88)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:371)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:245)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:125)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:246)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:112)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:87)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:311)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:257)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:169)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
       ...

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
     ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:311)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:257)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
  ...
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:132)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
  ...

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
79 actionable tasks: 79 executed
```

### Could you help me to fixing this problem or do you have any idea about this problem?

I tried to create new instances from Functions classes and use the instances at my view `viewModel.functions.getSuccessCategories(viewModel.uiState)` like this. It gave me below error.

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:54)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:311)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:257)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    ... 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessUiModel(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.generic.ui.ShowMessageBottomSheetUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_show_message_bottom_sheet.xml","pos":[{"line0":26,"col0":27,"line1":26,"col1":82}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessCategoryUIModel(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.add_or_update_category.ui.CategoryBottomSheetUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_category_bottom_sheet.xml","pos":[{"line0":60,"col0":37,"line1":60,"col1":106}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessCategories(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.home.HomeUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_home.xml","pos":[{"line0":29,"col0":30,"line1":29,"col1":88}]}

    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:859)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1265)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1404)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessUiModel(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.generic.ui.ShowMessageBottomSheetUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_show_message_bottom_sheet.xml","pos":[{"line0":26,"col0":27,"line1":26,"col1":82}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessCategoryUIModel(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.add_or_update_category.ui.CategoryBottomSheetUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_category_bottom_sheet.xml","pos":[{"line0":60,"col0":37,"line1":60,"col1":106}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getSuccessCategories(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.home.HomeUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_home.xml","pos":[{"line0":29,"col0":30,"line1":29,"col1":88}]}

    at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:114)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:123)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Any more information if you run with `--stacktrace` as suggested?

Comment: Thank you for response @ColinAlworth . I added stacktrace logs

Comment: It looks like your processor isn't running by the time its output is needed, or its output is not available for the android databinding processor. How is the processor configured in the project?, how is kaptDebugKotlin's classpath, task dependencies configured? (I'm familiar with Gradle and Annotation Processors, but haven't written an Android app in over a decade, and don't know Android development uses Gradle).

Comment: I implemented my annotation project with below implementation and processor handler.
`implementation project(path: ':annotation')`
 `kapt project(path: ':annotation')`
And i included annotation project at settings.gradle file
`include ':annotation'`
Additionally i created a function provider class to provide functions class objects and i used this objects to access methods. But it gave new error :)

`
ERROR: cannot find method getSuccessUiModel(com.duhapp.dnotes.features.generic.ui.ShowMessageBottomSheetUIState) in class error.NonExistentClass 
`

Comment: Post the new error in full in the question?

Comment: I added logs, but they are missing due to the character count limit.